# neo4j - pagination return same results even when skip and order by are specified

Tags: neo4j, nosql

I'm implementing infinite scroll and trying to get new items every time the user reach the bottom of the page.

problem is, neo4j return nodes that were already returned.

I read that `ORDER BY` is must for this case, but it didn't help.

I tried follow the solution here: [How to paginate query results with cypher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338670/how-to-paginate-query-results-with-cypher), and put the `pagination clauses (LIMIT, SKIP...)` before the `WITH` clause, but it didn't work. It also throw an error

the query:

```
MATCH(shops: Shop)
WHERE shops.title = ~ '(?i).*${search}.*'
WITH shops
ORDER BY shops.title asc
SKIP $skip
LIMIT $limit
MATCH(products: Product) < -[relation: SELL] - (shops)
RETURN shops, products, relation
```

how the query can guarantee new items on each request ?

*note - the `limit` is always 12, and `skip` is the items array length, the client app contain on the request.

**EDIT 1 - IMAGES FROM THE DB OF THE DUPLICATION**

it can be shown that a node with the same id, is returned from the two queries.

**1ST page - skip 0, limit 12**

[image: 1st page - skip 0, limit 12]

**2ND page - skip 12, limit 12**

[image: 2ND page - skip 12, limit 12]

Comment: What do you want paginate? Shop titles or products?

Comment: @fbiville shops

Comment: What's an item? A shop? A product? Something else?

Comment: @fbiville i try to paginate Shop. i want to get 12 new Shops every request. but, i get in 2nd request a shop that was returned on the first request.

Comment: First page: `skip = 0`, `limit 12`. 
Second page: `skip = 12`, `limit 12`. 
Third page: `skip = 24`, `limit 12`.
etc

Those values should do what you want, i.e. `limit = 12`, `skip = (pageNumber - 1) * limit` (assuming first page number is 1).

Comment: @fbiville thats the issue. 1st page: skip 0, limit 12. 2nd: skip 12 limit 12. 3rd: skip 24 limit 12. still, on the 2nd page one of the shops, already returned in the 1st page.

Comment: Do you reproduce this issue by running the queries directly against Neo4j?
How many shops do you have in total in the DB `MATCH(shops: Shop) RETURN COUNT(shops)`?

Comment: @fbiville yes I run it against the DB and see that I get a shop in the 2nd page, that was on the 1st. I have 69 shops

Comment: @fbiville if it helps, I added images of the issue live in EDIT 1.

Comment: If you truncate the query to just: `MATCH(shops: Shop)
WHERE shops.title = ~ '(?i).*${search}.*'
RETURN shops
ORDER BY shops.title asc
SKIP $skip
LIMIT $limit`, does the same problem happen?

Comment: @fbiville yes still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227859/discussion-between-fbiville-and-itay-tur).

Comment: @fbiville hey, thank you for your help. we found the solution, I added it at the bottom. have a great weekend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j doesn't have fallback when the `order by` is facing 2 or more nodes with the same value. I tried to `order by` the `title` `Timer` and there is several of `Shops` with this `title`. the work around was adding the fallback to another comparison.

`ORDER BY shops.title, shops.id`

weird that neo4j doesn't provide failsafe ( like, id of the node ), and resolving in sending the same node when skip is used.